# Iterating through a Perl array from an AJAX request

Tags: arrays, perl, catalyst

I'm working on a Catalyst database project and trying to do some AJAX requests via jQuery. Parameters are being sent OK, as can be seen in image 1.

[image: List of parameters and values received in AJAX request]

Notice that both "diagnosis" and "type_consents" (and their corresponding dates) are sent as an array of values (value 1, value 2, ... value n).

Now for the server side treatment, [`Catalyst::Request`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Request) allows for easy data retrieval through `$req->parameters`, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I'm doing it like this:

```
my $params = $c->request->parameters; #Retrieving all parameters

my @type_consents         = $params->{type_consent};
my @date_consents         = $params->{date_consent};
my @diagnosis             = $params->{diagnosis};
my @date_diagnosis        = $params->{date_diagnosis};
```

Then I need to loop these arrays and make an insertion for each pair of values `(diagnosis|date , consent|date)`. Plus, I need to store and process all transactions and execute them all at once in an `eval()` block, so I'm doing it like this:

```
my %transactions;

# Diagnosis
my $diag_index = 0;

foreach my $key ( 0 .. $#diagnosis ) {
    $transactions{diagnosis}{$diag_index} = $diagnosis_mod->new(
        {
            subject_id          => $subject_id,
            diagnosis_date      => $date_diagnosis[$key],
            diagnosis           => $diagnosis[$key],
            diagnosis_comment   => "",
            suggested_treatment => ""
        }
    );

    print STDERR "\n" . $date_diagnosis[$diag_index];
    print STDERR "\n DEBUG: $date_diagnosis[$diag_index] | $diagnosis[$diag_index] | key: $diag_index";
    print STDERR "\n DEBUG2:" . Dumper( @date_diagnosis ) . " | " . Dumper( @diagnosis );

    $diag_index++;
}

# I'm avoiding evaluating and performing the transactions so neither eval() nor database impact are shown above.
```

Those debugs print the following:

[image: Debugs of array iteration]

Does this suggest that my "array" is just a unidimensional variable with a string? I tried splitting it but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only values you can store in a hash are scalars.  Thus, `$params->{type_consent}` is a scalar, not a list.  However, since references to things (scalars, arrays, hashes, objects, globs, etc.) are also scalars, you can store references in a hash.

What `$params->{type_consent}` is, therefore, is a reference to an array, not an array or list itself.

What I think you want, then, is either to assign that to `my $type_consent = $params->{type_consent};` and then use `@$type_consent` as your array (and thus they both point at the same array - changing something through `@$type_consent` changes that array in `%$params`), *or* copy the array by saying `my @type_consent = @{$params->{type_consent}};`.

Which one I choose to use is situational, but I tend towards the reference option if only to keep memory usage down if there is no reason to copy it.

Comment: Well both did pretty good. Thanks a lot, @Tanktalus. I personally think second option is a little bit easier to read, so I'm going with that one, but both worked :)

Comment: I was doing some testing and it seems like this works fine ONLY when 2 or more elements are being sent.

I receive this error whenever 1 element (minimum acceptable for request) is sent:

`[error] Caught exception in pbitdb::Controller::Subjects->add "Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /home/lioneluranl/svn/pbitdb/pbitdb/script/../lib/pbitdb/Controller/Subjects.pm line 119."`

... where in this case "1" is the value sent... and the line referenced is the one where I declare the list: 
`my @type_consents         = @{$params->{type_consent}};`
Any ideas?

Comment: IMO, it's poor design to have dynamic types - a key that can have a scalar value *or* an array (reference) value. However, if the API you're calling is not under your control, you may have to deal with it in your code: `my @type_consent = ref $params->{type_consent} ? @{$params->{type_consent}} : $params->{type_consent};` Similar for keeping as reference: `my $tc = ref $params->{type_consent} ? $params->{type_consent} : [ $params->{type_consent} ]`

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately that's the way the API works :( . I didn't even know I could do that "either one or the other" thing in perl. Thanks A LOT. <3